# How to add a nonce to an inline script in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add a nonce to the inline scripts inserted in WordPress by wp_add_inline_script and wp_localize_script, but I can't figure out how to do it. It looks there are no WordPress filters for that. My goal is to have a nonce for inline scripts, so I can define a Content Security Policy that would not break common plugins that insert inline scripts. At the end the result should be something that looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="xxxxxxxxxx">....</script>
```

where xxxxxxxx is the nonce.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: check this link https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#strict-dynamic-usage and this https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/39941 ... I don't have any idea , I 'm also looking for this.

Comment: thank you for your comment. If you look at the second link you have provided, on the bottom you will see my question :) Reading the first link, we could think to use hashes instead of nonces, but I also don't figure out how to create an hash for each inline script, I don't see any hook to do that.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/shadyvb/574ead376eda7617e0f5e2a061815665 check this link if this helpful

Answer (score 1):

As the HTML for inline scripts are generated by the WordPress code

```
sprintf( "<script type='text/javascript'>\n%s\n</script>\n", ... )
```

you cannot add an attribute to the HTML script element using wp_add_inline_script() as `<script type='text/javascript'>` is hard coded.

However, the filter 'script_loader_tag' will allow you to change the HTML for script elements just before it is outputted by WordPress.

Note that the filter 'script_loader_tag' will not be applied to script elements added by calling wp_localize_script() since these are outputted by the WordPress code:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n"; // CDATA and type='text/javascript' is not needed for HTML 5
echo "/* <![CDATA[ */\n";
echo "$output\n";
echo "/* ]]> */\n";
echo "</script>\n";
```

Since these are echoed and `<script type='text/javascript'>` is hard coded you cannot add an attribute to the HTML script elements of wp_localize_script().

Comment: thank you very much for your comment. I had already tried with the filter script_loader_tag but without success. On my opinion the possibility to add a nonce to inline scripts should be provided by the WordPress core. As it is now it looks impossible to implement a serious Content Security Policy without break third parties plugins that haven't taken it in account. For building a single site it's easier. My goal was to make a theme that could support the CSP, but if the user decides to activate it, all the inline scripts of the common plugins as WooCommerce will be deactivated. I will renounce

Comment: The filter for ''script_loader_tag' should work for everything but the scripts added by wp_localize_script(). When WordPress does not have an action/filter to do what you need you can always modify the WordPress core - not best practice but absolutely necessary. Regarding WordPress and CSP I remember thinking about it several years ago and coming to the conclusion it would be very hard to do.

Comment: Incidentally, modifying the WordPress core can be done in minimally intrusive manner. In this case I would remove the 'wp_head' action 'wp_print_head_scripts' and replace it with my own action. My action would use my own class extension of the core class WP_Scripts. There is only one method WP_Scripts::print_extra_script() you need to modify and that modification is trivial.

Comment: The main point of modifying the WordPress core in the way I have described is that when a site updates WordPress that site should still run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use wp_enqueue_scripts hook

```
function my_special_inline_script() {
    ?>
    <script>
        // your JS code
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_special_inline_script', 1, 1 );
```

or

```
function theme_prefix_enqueue_script() {
   wp_add_inline_script( 'jquery', 'jQuery(document).ready(function(){});' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_prefix_enqueue_script' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party but I just faced this exact problem for the same reasons.

I solved it for `wp_add_inline_script` by a bit of simple `str_replace` action.

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_nonce_to_script_tag', 10, 3 );

function add_nonce_to_script_tag( $tag, $handle, $src ) {

  // Check the $handle and respond accordingly
  if ( $handle === 'my-script' ) {
    $nonce_value = wp_create_nonce('my__script__nonce'); // or ref to an existing nonce
    $replace = sprintf("javascript' nonce='%s'>", $nonce_value );
    $tag = str_replace( "javascript'>", $replace, $tag);
  }

  return $tag;
}

// Then... $data is the inline JS from wherever
wp_add_inline_script('my-script', $data, 'before');
```

Once the inline script loads, I am seeing the `script` tag output with a nonce attribute. This is working fine with my Content-Security-Policy.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this out](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/02/23/introducing-script-attributes-related-functions-in-wordpress-5-7/)
"WordPress 5.7 adds a handful of new functions that enables passing attributes, such as async or **nonce**"